# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- academic websites and resources
- interesting campus story blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2148).

Comment: Do we have to follow the template or can we use an `<a href=""><img src=""></a>`

Comment: Have to use the template

Answer (score 28):

[image: arXiv.org: the leading open access eprint repository]

Comment: Edited version of [this 2014 Physics ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/posts/5266/revisions). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arXiv%20ad%202016%202.svg).

Answer (score 21):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/hsm%20ad%202016.svg), working off of [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Diophantus_title_I_1621.jpg).

Answer (score 20):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/retraction%20watch%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [Earliest Detexify ad I know of](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/community-promotion-ads-2013/11616#11616). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/detexify%20ad%202016.svg)

Answer (score 16):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scicomp%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 15):

[image: Pubpeer.com]

Comment: This looks blurry

Comment: @becko it's a screenshot, you're welcome to contact the site admin to ask for a vector version.

Comment: They sent me an .svg. What do I do with it? How can I add it here?

Comment: Or I could send it to you?

Comment: @becko neat! upload on imgur and provide the link, I will edit my post with the better version.

Comment: @becko I don't know if you need a certain reputation to edit this post, but if you see the "edit" function below the post, then you are welcome to edit yourself.

Comment: http://imgh.us/logo_213.svg ... I cant edit, please you do it.

Comment: @becko did they really send this? It's not the same font as the homepage.

Comment: It's what they sent.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Wayback Machine: experience the Web as it was]

Comment: Edited from [this 2014 Physics ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5733). [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/wayback%20machine%20ad%202016.svg); requires the fonts Iconochive and Agfa Rotis Semi Serif.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Zotero reference manager: free and open source]

Comment: Originally posted on the [2016 Physics thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7437/8563). [Inkskape source SVG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/zotero%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 13):

[image: The Cost of Knowledge - join the Elsevier boycott and take back our scientific publishing!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Comment: cross-ref: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2712/4945

Comment: Below text setting me bit of.

Comment: @Ankit Could you expand on that comment a bit? Are you upset that I cross-referenced the source?

Comment: no, i mean the text below the beakers, site address. Specially the font.

Comment: @Ankit we had a fair amount of talk about it in chat. You are welcome to grab the source and experiment yourself. It was the best I could come up with.

Comment: fair enough but i am not good with this stuff to start with anyways ;)

Answer (score 11):

[image: cryptography.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Hi. [I've copied your ad over in Physics Meta too](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7487/46399). I hope that's OK.

Comment: @TheDarkSide Sure. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 10):

[image: Are your papers available in an open access repository? Check with Dissemin]

Comment: Image file now at https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAnRi.png

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Eh, I don't see much point in updating three-year old Community Promotion ads (as they no longer impact the live ads, but sure.

Answer (score 10):

[image: For those seeking down-to-earth answers to their questions]

Answer (score 8):

[image: archive.org - the public library of the internet]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/internet%20archive%20ad%202016.svg); requires the fonts Iconochive and Agfa Rotis Semi Serif. Comments on the design welcome.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Law.SE]

Answer (score 4):

[image: physicsoverflow.org]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 4):

[image: OpenScience Q&A]

Answer (score 3):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Comment: [First arXiv Analytics ad I know of](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6127/8563). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arxiv%20analytics%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 3):

[image: We train scientists how to connect to the public, back scientists in their outreach, and crowdfund to support research. The goal? A more science engaged world.]

Answer (score 2):

[image: arXiv.org - over a million papers, free to access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/arXiv%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Open Science]

Comment: Note to the mods / admins: Maybe consider allowing the use of Area51 images instead of forcing us to re-upload to imgur, as this way, the number of followers is not updated on the community promotion ad.

Comment: You could have used an Area 51 image yourself – see my edit.

Comment: Huh, interesting, it didn't let me do that when I tried that exact code. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The by SE staff in private beta closed Open Science community has been successfully revived outside the SE network at the German University of Bielefeld, where it is allowed to gather momentum at its own natural pace without being threatend to get closed again against the will of the community: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2208/5904

Answer (score 2):

[image: Digital Open Access Identifier - a DOI resolver that prioritizes open access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/doai%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: thanks for the ad! We think doai.io is not really easy to use for now and we're working on a new version, which should go live in the coming months hopefully.

Comment: @pintoch Cool! This one isn't live, but [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/8795/8563) is. I really like the project but I agree it can improve. I had some trouble with a particular doi some weeks ago (dunno if I can find it again, though), but I couldn't find anywhere to report it. Is there some issue tracker / support email / similar?

Comment: That's exactly one of the things we'd like to improve. For now you can use our issue tracker https://github.com/dissemin/proaixy/issues.

Comment: @pintoch Cool, I'll keep that in mind if I find a problematic one. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @pintoch Is [this](https://github.com/dissemin/proaixy/issues/11) the place for that? It certainly needs a link on the doai.io front page that says what to do with links like that.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Open Source Licenses in Plain English]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Comment: [The chat room dedicated to this proposal](http://goo.gl/VxYdsL)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/socarxiv%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 0):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: Edited form of the [earliest SciRate ad I know of](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5982/8563). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scirate%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score -1):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Great! great!   Great

Answer (score -3):

[image: Effective Altruism SE proposal]

Answer (score -7):

[image: Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs]

Comment: I don't like this add since I have no idea from the image where I am going to end up.

Comment: Why? There is a google docs logo in the image, I think it would be self-explanatory that it leads to a google doc. Is it better to link to our website rather than the direct install page (an additional click away from install?)

Comment: Unless you already know the logo, from the image the most we can tell is that it goes to a google doc related to LaTeX and equations. Further, the link has a referral code which I also do not like. Why not build an ad around the logo?

Comment: It doesn't only go to a Google Doc; the doc is just a gateway to the add-on store (which is free anyways). The code does not track users in any way, just tells me that I got a website hit. What do you mean by "ad around the logo"? I want a simple, picture-based ad with minimal text, and don't want to compromise the design.

Comment: I mean something like the [zotero ad](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2151/929) with the logo and some explanation.

Comment: My color scheme is radically different from that ad, and I don't currently posses the design experience necessary to make it visually appealing. Got suggestions for color/background/sizing?